# Why do we have to explicitly specify "this" when invoking an extension method from within a method of a class being extended?

Tags: c#, .net, this, extension-methods

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        // implicitly specified instance does not work
        //return GetMemberName();

        // must specify this explicitly
        return this.GetMemberName();
    }
}

public static class Utilities
{
    public static string GetMemberName(this Controller caller,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        return caller.GetType().FullName + "." + memberName;
    }
}
```

Why do we have to explicitly specify `this` when invoking an extension method from within a method of a class being extended?

In my mental model, we usually can omit `this` such as when we initialize fields, for example.

Comment: How do you mean does not work ? Which exception occures ?

Comment: @Dejo: I got a compilation error.

Comment: As Eric Lippert might say, all features are unimplemented by default. So the question is why you think this should be implemented. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being present at the design board meeting where this was decided it's hard to say why it's like that.

In this text I use method or instance method in the sense of a function associated with a specific object instance and I use function in a mathematical sense. A function receives a number of arguments and creates a result (which is potentially void)

If we do not consider virtual methods which are more complex because the actual function to be called is determined runtime then **any and all** method calls are syntactic sugar. If we have two methods defined below

```
internal static class Extensions {
  public static string FooEx(this MyClass self){
     return self.ToString();
  }
}

internal class MyClass {
  public string Bar(){
     var s1 = Foo();
     var s2 = this.FooEx();
  }

  private string Foo(){
      return ToString();
  }
}
```

Then both will be translated to a function call where the first (and only) argument in **both** cases will be the object identified by `this`. If you are doubtful about this then look at the IL produced for any call to an instance method and you will notice there's an extra argument compared to the declaration in code. This argument is the `this`reference, which is **always** passed as the first argument to an instance method.

So in the case of an instance method the compiler still need to determine which object to pass as the first argument to the function. That is **exactly** the same it has to do if you are calling an extension method without `this` which also means that can't be the real reason why you have to use `this` in front of an extension method.

In the compiler for [Marvin](http://fullOO.info), a compiler build on top of the Mono compiler I had to do a similar trick as C# does with extension methods and wondered why the specs require the `this` 
The real reason why the compiler enforces you to use `this` before an extension method is that the specs says so. What the reason behind that decision is would need the attention of some one like @EricLippert who where probably there when they decided on that requirement

Answer (score 3):

An extension method is technically not a method attached to your class.

`yourClass.ExtensionMethod()` isn't the same as `yourClass.ClassMethod()`.

Basically, what you are doing is getting a convenient way of doing this:

```
ExtensionMethod(YourClass yourClass) {
    //do something
    return yourClass;
}
```

That is my understanding of an extension method. It's a convenient way of calling a method against a class you can't change. So, that's why you can't just call it without `this.` It's not a class method.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why the compiler can rewrite 'InstanceMethod' to 'this.InstanceMethod' but can't rewrite 'ExtensionMethod' to 'this.ExtensionMethod'

Comment: @RuneFS Feel free to contribute.

Comment: I would if I knew the design decision behind it but since I don't I can't

Comment: Whoever down-voted me, care to explain? Add a comment or edit the answer to improve it. Just down-voting doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Extension method is just a syntactic sugar to call a static method. Tthis line of code `return this.GetMemberName();` is actually convert to a call to static method like `Utilities.GetMemberName(this);`

As you can see, you have to send `this` to the static method and that is the reason why you need `this` keyword.

Comment: That does explain why the compiler in one case can deduce the missing identifier whereas in a similar context it can't

Comment: @RuneFS Feel free to contribute.